US Treasury Futures Wildcard Option
How does the conversion factor for bonds impact the valuation of the wildcard option?
In the WN contract, bonds with lower coupons/conversion factors, have higher wildcard options and I am wondering why this is.

Excercising your wildcard option involves you buying or selling the "tail" of your basis position in the market (tail = (1-CF) bonds).
When the CF > 1 you are usually holding too many futures relative to your spot position (when the settlement price for the future is fixed at the pit close). Therefore, you must buy more bonds. And vice versa when the CF < 1.
CFs (Conversion Factors) are usually less than 1 at the moment (lower coupons tend to have lower CFs all else the same). Therefore, excercising your wildcard involves you selling spot post futures close. The lower the CF the more tail you have to sell, therefore, technically this brings the strike of the wildcard closer to you. More intuitively you need less of a move in the cash market to recoup the gross basis you are losing by excercising the option.

Thank you! this is very helpful
